# Como posso formatar esse array para a maneira que eu quero?

Tags: php, array

Estou criando um `Seeder` para o `Laravel` inserir valores em uma tabela `N para N`.

Eu estou montando o `array` de uma forma, porém preciso que no final ele "se torne" em outra. Isso porque quero evitar repetição constante de código (digitar repetidamente os mesmos itens do `array`.

O `array` que eu tenho é o seguinte:

```
  $niveis[3] = [
        $can('VendaController@getIndex'),
        $can('VendaController@anyEditar'),
        $can('VendaController@anyCriar'),
 ];

 $niveis[14] = [
        $can('ProdutoController@getIndex'),
        $can('UsuarioController@anyEditar'),
        $can('UsuarioController@anyCriar'),
 ];
```

Isso gera um `array` assim:

```
 [ 
   3 => [1, 55, 87],
   14 => [45, 78, 101]
]
```

Porém eu preciso que a partir desse `array`, eu possa montar ele da seguinte forma:

```
[
      [ 'nivel_id' => 3, 'permissao_id' => 1],
      [ 'nivel_id' => 3, 'permissao_id' => 55],
      [ 'nivel_id' => 3, 'permissao_id' => 87],
      // E assim por diante

   ]
```

Ou seja, preciso transformar a `key` em `nivel_id` com o valor dela, e repetir enquanto tiver algum valor dentro do `array` referente à ela.

Como fazer isso em PHP, de um jeito menos complicado possível?

Comment: Boa pergunta +1

Comment: @rray tenho a pequena impressão que isso nos levará à um `array_map` com dois parâmetros

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que entendi, é isso:

```
 $array = [ 
   3 => [1, 55, 87],
   14 => [45, 78, 101]
];


 $novoArray = [];

 foreach($array as $key => $subArray) {
    foreach($subArray as $value) {
        $novoArray[] = [
           'nivel_id' => $key, 'permissao_id' => $value
         ];
    }
 }


 print_r($novoArray);
```

Comment: É, estou  pensando, pensando, pensando... E ainda só encontrei esse jeito mesmo...

Answer (score 0):

Não tem como fugir muito do loop.

Basicamente você irá percorrer o primeiro indice, pegando o nivel. Cada nivel deverá pegar as permissões e assim mapear um novo array com o novo formato.

Segue um exemplo:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0f6c7b70e99a3c2905e6c0887118f20b2c13d2ba